# Invalid Column Name for computed column?

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, ssms-2017

I have the following query, that works just fine if I comment out the part that is the reason for my question (as I've already done below).

```
Declare @mPoint As varchar(50) = 'POINT (-107.657141 41.033581)'
Declare @iRadius As int = 5000 --5km for testing. 4 results, 1 with PriorityType = 0.

SELECT FLOOR([Position].STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText(@mPoint, 4326))) AS Distance,
    CASE 
        WHEN [Type] & 64 = 64 THEN 0
        --insert other types as needed. 
        ELSE 1000 
    END AS PriorityType,
    *
FROM [tblAddress]
WHERE DeletedOn IS NULL 
    --AND Distance <= @iRadius --        <-- This is Line 13
ORDER BY PriorityType ASC, Distance ASC;
```

This query should filter about 1700 records in a database and based on the above *(static)* results, return 4 rows, of which one has a `PriorityType` of 0.

The thing is, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS for short) gives me the error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'Distance'.
```

And a red line below the 'Distance' of `AND Distance <= @iRadius`.

If I comment out that line (as in the example above), I get the entire table as required. Clearly, the column is present! So why do I get the error?

Comment: You can't reference a column in your `SELECT` in your `WHERE`, as the `WHERE` is determined **before** the `SELECT`. you would need to use a CTE/Subquery or repeat the expression in your `WHERE`.

Comment: Where clause will be executed before Select clause. Distance is the Alias name  you are giving in where clause. So query will not find Distance column. So try writing FLOOR([Position].STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText(@mPoint, 4326))) in where clause instead of Distance or write sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified solution,

`Declare @mPoint As varchar(50) = 'POINT (-107.657141 41.033581)' 
Declare @iRadius As int = 5000 
SELECT FLOOR([Position].STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText(@mPoint, 4326))) AS Distance,
CASE WHEN [Type] & 64 = 64 THEN 0
ELSE 1000 END AS PriorityType, 
*
FROM [tblAddress] 
WHERE DeletedOn IS NULL AND  FLOOR([Position].STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText(@mPoint, 4326)))<= @iRadius
ORDER BY PriorityType ASC, Distance ASC;`